# Sur « ait se soit »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

> Le plus jeune Président de la République que la France [ait se
>   soit](http://www.atlantico.fr/decryptage/emmanuel-macron-etrange-victoire-3042161.html) jamais donné, réalise un score sans appel, supérieur de
>   quelques points aux prévisions des derniers sondages de la fin de
>   semaine.

Je ne peux tout simplement pas comprendre cette agglomération de deux verbes au subjonctif, *ait* et *soit*, dans l'espace étroit de juste trois mots, dont un est la marque de la voix pronominale, le pronom *se*.

Et *se soit* ? Je ne savais pas que le verbe *être* a un homologue pronominal, *s'être*.

Est-ce que ces trois mots représentent une simple coquille typographique ou font-ils partie d'une expression idiomatique que jusqu'aujourd'hui je n'ai jamais vue ?

Comment: Le plus jeune Président que la France ait jamais connue....

Comment: Whether “ait jamais eu” or “se soit jamais donné” was intended, I’m puzzled why the subjunctive was used here at all. I realize that it’s used in clauses following superlatives, but I thought that usage only applied when personal opinions or judgments about the superlative nature of something were being expressed. That he's the youngest, however, is a fact. If my understanding about this use w/superlatives (i.e., for personal opinions/judgments only) is correct, I wonder if the fact that President-**elect** Macron has not yet been inaugurated could be the reason for using the subjunctive here?

Comment: *[...] que les Français se soient jamais donné [...]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ça ressemble à mes phrases quand je fais un copié-collé, je corrige un bout, et j'oublie un mot au milieu.

Le journaliste a peut-être commencé par écrire:

> Le plus jeune que la France n'ait jamais eu.

Puis il a changé d'avis, et voulu écrire:

> Le plus jeune que la France ne se soit jamais donné.

Ça ressemble à un mélange entre les deux.

En tout cas "ait se soit", difficile de faire cohabiter ces deux verbes avoir et être, sans que ce soit une erreur. Personnellement, jamais vu avoir + être qui se suivent nulle part.

Comment: "jamais vu avoir + être qui se suivent nulle part." Je suppose que tu voulais dire "qui se suivent *quelque part*". Ou plutôt "(je n'ai) jamais vu avoir + être se suivre ?". De toutes façons dire ça sans autre explication est faux. Le passé composé du verbe être se composant avec *avoir*, on a bien une forme du verbe *être* qui suit une forme du verbe *avoir*.

Comment: Je ne les ai jamais vu se suivre, nulle part.

Comment: Donc la conclusion finale : c'est une erreur, non ?

Comment: Pour moi, oui, c'est une erreur. À mon avis, un mauvais copié-collé, car c'est étrangement un mélange des 2 formules. Ma réponse n'est pas assez claire? Je peux l'éditer si besoin.

Comment: Tout clair maintenant. Merci!

Answer (score 3):

A mon avis c'est simplement une erreur, la phrase souhaitée devait être "Le plus jeune Président de la République que la France se soit jamais donné, réalise un score sans appel, supérieur de quelques points aux prévisions des derniers sondages de la fin de semaine."

Comment: Que la France se soit ... donné, ce verbe est au subjonctif passé, non?

Comment: Oui, mais je pense qu'il manque la négation. Que la France ne se soit jamais donné. Sinon, ça fait un peu modelé sur le "ever" anglais, qui n'a pas besoin de négation.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Il ne manque pas de négation dans cette phrase. *Jamais* a ici un sens positif. "Dans son sens positif, jamais veut dire « un jour quelconque, une fois, un moment passé ou futur ». On l'emploie souvent dans ce sens pour introduire une condition, dans une comparaison ou dans une phrase interrogative." [bdl](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3093).

Comment: Tu as raison: c'est une hyper correction apparemment.